# Как можно нормально оформить RecyclerView android?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня в приложении есть список RecyclerView, сейчас этот список выглядит страшно и некрасиво. Я вот на данный момент просматриваю виды оформления списка, и все они имеют какой-то устаревший на мой взгляд дизайн ,большие тени, эффекты 3d и кучу старого оформления. Может кто-то работал с какой-то нормальной библиотекой, нужно что-бы список выглядел не серо(я не про цвет говорю) и был достаточно красивым для обычного пользователя, сделать разделители элементов списка, выделение цветом при нажатии и тд. Или-же нужно делать свои стили, и все прописывать самостоятельно под свои цели? Вот например есть такой [список](http://camposha.info/user/pages/demos/source/recyclerviewsort/demo1.gif) там уже есть инструкция, хочется создать что-то на подобии такого списка, но немного его изменить согласно моим взглядам на прекрасное))
Заранее спасибо за помощь и полезные советы.

Comment: понятие красивого у людей разное, приведите какой то скриншот, что ли, что по вашему не страшное, а желанное. А вообще да, вы можете оформить свой список как вам угодно - вы используете собственный айтем, рисуйте и красьте там, как хотите. Так же есть класс `ItemDecoration` для кастомного оформления и ItemAnimator для собственных анимаций

Comment: добавил ссылку на пример списка.

Comment: не вижу в вашем списке особых изысков - он стандартный. в качестве корневого элемента айтема - `CardView` этот виджет дает и тень и скругления, больше я там вообще никаких дизайнерских решений не вижу ...

Comment: да после ознакомления с `CardView` я понял что приведенный пример можно реализовать при помощи этого виджета довольно легко)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут именно цветов вопрос. Сам по себе список - это не более чем переиспользование одних и тех же элементов. Поэтому в ваших руках всё, что вам надо. Можете сделать по гайдам Material Design, использовать CardView для элемента списка, сделать ему foreground = "?attr:seleсtableItemBackground" и clickable = "true" для риппл эффекта при нажатии. Можете кастомизировать цвет этого риппла через аттрибуты, или нарисовать свою анимацию. Можете раскрасить любыми градиентами свои элементы.

Вам не по андроиду надо задавать вопрос, а читать гайды по дизайну и совершенствовать своё видение. Я за несколько лет работы не встречл либ с дизайном, только с реализацией каких то поведенческих вещей, если говорить о элементах интерфейса. сам же интерфейс растёт из голов дизайнеров и подаётся при помощи фотошопа, скетча, цеплина или ещё чего. Скетч, кстати, вроде умеет в стандартные экраны и android и ios телефонов и знает многие стандартные элементы, что помогает рисовать дизайн именно под мобильные устройства, но это не точно ))) (сам я им не пользовался)

Программирование под андроид, как и любое другое программирование, которое умеет в создание интерфейсов - это просто инструмент подачи интерфейса пользователю. Сам интерфейс - дело дизайнера.

Советую почитать про material design, потому что список, который вы прислали сделан по гайдам именно его. Использованы цвета из палитры material design и более того, цвета, которые студия по умолчанию подсовывает в новый проект. В качестве элементов выбраны элементы CardView - это библиотека андроида, подключите - и у вас будет такая красивая штука с тенями и скругленными углами.

Пока писал вспомнил - в Google Play Market есть приложение, которое называется Libraries For Developers, скачайте и посмотрите, автор себе в приложение насовал демок всяких библиотек с ссылками на гитхаб, возможно там вы найдёте для себя что то интересное.

Comment: да я видел это приложение, довольно интересный проект для помощи разработчикам, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: "потому что список, который вы прислали сделан по гайдам" в демке всё сделано прямо против гайдов, использование акцентных цветов, для кнопок, черный шрифт на акценте, железное правило 16dp отступы, шрифт с акцентым цветом, FAB не гайдовский, Toolbar не toolbar, cardView elevation 2dp а там все 10+ стоит, в простом примере нарушили всё что можно. Даже просто если на этот список применить гайды, а потом заполнить контентом, всё заиграет подругому

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Я не дизайнер, я просто увидел знакомые элементы)